# File inplace replacement without awk or sed

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk

I have a file in which I would to replace whatever is between position 100-119 with "X" and our Linux system awk or sed doesn't support -i (inplace) replacement. Could you please help with alternative to run a command which will help to replace record which starts with "D"

Comment: Use `awk '...' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`

Comment: Would like to run a single command across lot of files started with master_file_YYYYMMDD - There are about 9000 files against which need to run this command

Comment: That should not matter. Even `-i inplace` does same behind the scene.

Comment: Ok, you mean with above command it will work for multiple files as well?

Comment: Add some sample input and complete expected output for those samples. Add the code you currently have. `perl` and `ed` are possible options for in-place editing

Comment: Is your question a) how to write a script to `replace whatever is between position 100-119 with "X"` or b) `replace record which starts with "D"` or c) how to do inplace editing when you don't have a sed or awk that directly supports it? In either case, please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output that demonstrate just the problem you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 2):

Use this Perl one-liner with [`substr`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 'substr( $_, (100 - 1), (119 - 100 + 1) ) = "X"' file1 file2 ...
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`.

`substr( $_, (100 - 1), (119 - 100 + 1) ) = "X"` : Take the input line `$_` and replace the contents between positions 100 and 119 with `X`. Note that `substr` indexes positions starting with 0, so `100 - 1` is used here assuming that your positions are numbered starting with 1.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)

Answer (score 2):

All any command `cmd` that has an "inplace editing" option (awk, sed, perl, ruby, etc.) does is this behind the scenes:

```
tmp=$(mktemp) && cmd 'script' "$file" > "$tmp" && mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
```

so you can always just write that yourself.

For any given command `cmd` (i.e. `sed`, or `awk`, or `cut`, or `tail` or `grep`, or anything else) here's how you can create and call an "inplace editing" version that'll work just like the tools that have a `-i` type of option for "inplace editing" for multiple input files:

```
cmd_inplace() {
    local tmp file
    tmp=$(mktemp) &&
    for file; do
        cmd 'script' "$file" > "$tmp" &&
        mv -- "$tmp" "$file"
    done
}

cmd_inplace master_file_*
```

Just replace `cmd` with the name of whatever command you want to call and `cmd 'script'` with whatever you want it to do.