# Bash - Update a value in a file using sed command

Tags: awk, sed

I am trying to update the value of key1[count] to 2 in the following file.

```
#file1

//some additional lines
key1   = { var1 = "1", var2 = "12", "count" = 1 }
key2 = { var1 = "32", var2 = "23", "count" = 1 }
key3    = { var1 = "22", var2 = "32", "count" = 3 }
key4    = { var1 = "32", var2 = "12", "count" = 3 }
//some additional lines
```

I had tried using awk - `awk -i inplace '{ if ( $1 == "key1" ) $12 = 2 ; print $0 }' file1`.
However, this only works with awk version 4.1.0 and higher.

Comment: Are you asking how to change the values as you want or how to write the result of changing the values back to the input file? You said `this only works with...` so I assume your script actually does what you want and you're just trying to update the input file with the result, right? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228200/1745001 for how to overwrite input with any command and if you still have a question then please add a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk -v newVal="2" '
/^key1/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value)
  $0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Checking condition if line starts from `key1` and using `match` function to match regex `"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+` to get count string with its value here. Then with matched sub-string creating value(variable), where substituting digits at last of value to NULL. Then re-assigning value of current line to before match value, matched value, new value variable and rest of the line to make it as per OP's requirement. Finally by `1` printing current line(s).

***NOTE:*** Above will only print the output on terminal, once you are Happy with shown results append  `> temp && mv temp Input_file` to above code.

Comment: Tried the above command _
 `key1   = { var1 = "1", var2 = "12", "count" = 1 }`                          
Does not seem to replace the value by 2.

Comment: @SushmaKamat, As mentioned in my answer this will print all file values on terminal. Once you are happy with results then only use `-i inplace` to my code. If you want to use one liner try `awk -v newVal="\"2\"" '/^key1/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value);$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1' file` once and let me know then(its same code as posted but in a one liner form), let me know how it goes?

Comment: the main aim is to remove the usage of `-i inplace`. This only works on machines having a higher version of awk (i.e 4.1.0 and higher).  Using `awk -i inplace` gives error - `awk: unknown option -i ignored`

Comment: @SushmaKamat, oh ok then use like: `awk -v newVal="2" '/^key1/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value);$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'  file > temp && mv temp file` once and let me know how it goes?

Comment: Tried the command. Somehow, its not getting replaced in the file. `cat file1
#file1

key1   = { var1 = "1", var2 = "12", "count" = 1 }
key2 = { var1 = "32", var2 = "23", "count" = 1 }
key3    = { var1 = "22", var2 = "32", "count" = 3 }
key4    = { var1 = "32", var2 = "12", "count" = 3 }
` (one liner format)

Comment: @SushmaKamat, is your line always starting with `key1`? not having any spaces etc before it? Please confirm once.

Comment: @SushmaKamat, my code is tested and working fine with your shown samples. Its checking if a line starts with key1 then only it will move further in conditions. So please confirm as asked in my previous comment.

Comment: It starts with `key1` on a new line. The file may contain some lines before this line though.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am not sure why it is not working for me. It does start with key1 on a new line. I have used the command without any alteration.

Comment: @SushmaKamat, this command assumes that your `key1` and `count` are on same line like your shown samples, since you are saying its on new line, I would like to request you to edit your question once with actual sample of input so that I could see what's going on.

Comment: I have updated the question. `key1` and `count` are on the same line. And there might be some additional lines as mentioned in the question

Comment: @SushmaKamat, Trust me this is working with your updated samples also, it prints all other lines along with key1 updated line. Could you please do check once if you have control M characters in your file? Run a command: `cat -v file` and let me know if you see control M characters in it?

Comment: `cat -v file1
#file1

key1   = { var1 = "1", var2 = "12", "count" = 1 }
key2 = { var1 = "32", var2 = "23", "count" = 1 }
key3    = { var1 = "22", var2 = "32", "count" = 3 }
key4    = { var1 = "32", var2 = "12", "count" = 3 }`
This is my output.

Comment: @SushmaKamat, not sure if control M chars will be posted in stack overflow's comments or not. How about letting me know if you see them when you run command? It will be like `^M` etc see if you see any unusual chars on it's output?

Comment: I cannot see any such characters after running `cat -v file`

Comment: @SushmaKamat, then I am wondering why this code isn't working for you :( because this is working perfectly fine for me, let me add another approach also in 5 to 10 mins.

Comment: Sure!! Thanks for all your help

Comment: @SushmaKamat, Ok, how about using this command once `awk -v newVal="2" '/key1.*count/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value);$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'  file`? This will print lines on terminal see if its giving you expected results?

Comment: Okay, now I get it why it fails to work. `awk: option -v lacks argument`. Probably this version of awk doesnt support this

Comment: @SushmaKamat, may be copy/paste problem. This is a single line code. `awk -v newVal="2" '/key1.*count/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value);$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'  file` kindly use it in single line and it should work fine then

Comment: yes, it does work fine when I use this command on a machine where awk version is 4.2.1 and the same command fails on another machine where awk version is lower.

Comment: @SushmaKamat. Yes of above working fine then use this one for inplace edit `awk -v newVal="2" '/key1.*count/ && match($0,/"count"[[:space:]]+=[[:space:]]+[0-9]+/){value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);sub(/[0-9]+$/,"",value);$0=substr($0,1,RSTART-1) value newVal substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)} 1'  file > temp && mv temp file` in a single line please should work .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` with the `-r` option for regular expression.

For your example, you can use this command.

```
sed -i -r 's/(key1.*"count" = )([0-9]*)(.*)/\12\3/g' <file>
```

More information:

```
Command template:
    sed -i -r 's/(<bef>)(<tar>)(<aft>)/\1<new value>\3/g' <file>

Where
    <bef> is a regex that targets /key1... "count" = /
    <tar> is a regex that targets /1/
    <aft> is a regex that targets / }/

Together, /<bef><tar><aft>/ will expand to become:
    /key1   = { var1 = "1", var2 = "12", "count" = 1 }/

Since you want to replace "1" with "2"
    <new value> is 2
```

Comment: Thank you. This works!! Can you please explain the usage of `3` ?

Comment: `\1`, `\2` and `\3` are backreferences you can use to access the actual text captured by your regular expressions `<bef>`, `<tar>` and `<aft>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explaination!! I dont mind the messy reply :P